# Swap button click to exchange User-Default values and update values into TableView UI using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, swap

My scenario is , I am trying to exchange `NSUserdefault` values and `restore` it `immediately`. Here, I am having single button click action, once UIButton clicked I need to Swap my userdefault values and restore it. For Example: A Values Store Into B and B `Values` Store Into A. It should work again and again. The stored values I am using same `viewcontroller`. So, storage need to updated quickly.

My Code

```
 // MARK: Switch Language
    @IBAction func swapClick(_ sender: Any) {

            // I need to do exchange value and restore it immediately 
    UserDefaults.standard.set(default_from_ID, forKey: "To_ID") // from here
        UserDefaults.standard.set(default_to_ID, forKey: "From_ID") // to here

    }
```

Tableview Delegate

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = self.translation_tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TranslationCustomCell

        cell.from_label.text = "\(default_from_Name ?? "")"
        cell.to_label.text = "\(default_to_Name ?? "")"

        return cell
  }
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear; what outcome are enough looking for?  What happens?  What do you want to happen?

Comment: You are only storing data into user defaults. You aren't fetching anything *from* user defaults.

Comment: I am still not following you. You need to run some code to fetch the data from user defaults. How do you trigger that code after saving the new values? I.e. you need to reload the relevant cells.

Comment: @Paulw11I am asking how to swap it?

Comment: Swap what? You are saving two values into user defaults. You won't see any change in your UI unless you reload those values from user defaults.

Comment: I tried its not updating. @Paulw11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193635/discussion-between-paulw11-and-jackios).

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the values first, then set value in by swapping the keys

```
@IBAction func swapClick(_ sender: Any) {
    let values = (UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DFrom_Name"),UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DTo_Name"))
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(values.1, forKey: "DFrom_Name")
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(values.0, forKey: "DTo_Name")
    self.translation_tableview.reloadData()
}

UserDefaults.standard.setValue("London", forKey: "DFrom_Name")
UserDefaults.standard.setValue("NewYork", forKey: "DTo_Name")

print(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DFrom_Name"))//Optional("London")
print(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DTo_Name"))//Optional("NewYork")
swapClick(UIButton())
print(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DFrom_Name"))//Optional("NewYork")
print(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "DTo_Name"))//Optional("London")
```

Comment: Thank you @RajeshKumar...Now tableview not updating. I called reload even its not updating values inside UI.